# What makes Nullable type can be assigned a null?

Tags: c#, .net

We know that we can assign null to a nullable type. For example:

```
Nullable<Int32> x = 2021;
Nullable<Int32> y = null;
```

We know the second statement works because we were told it works, and we just take it and don't ask why.
But if you look at the source code of `Nullable<T>` is:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct {
   ...
   public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) {
      return new Nullable<T>(value);
   }
   public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value) {
      return value.Value; 
   }
}
```

The reason we can assign an `int` to `Nullable<Int32>` as `Nullable<Int32> x = 2021;`
is because of the implicit operator, which allow you implicit cast an int to `Nullable<Int32>`.
According to the rule of the implicit operator, `T` as the right hand side of `=`, has to be a struct type, but `null` is clearly not a legal struct value, so how can we do `Nullable<Int32> y = null;`(not to mention `Nullable<Int32>` itself is a struct)  and why it doesn't violate the implicit operator rule

Comment: It's explicitly covered by the language spec, and special-cased by the compiler

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#nullable-types) for some of the spec on nullable types, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#null-literal-conversions) for the bit saying there's an implicit conversion between `null` and a nullable value type. `Nullable<T>` is very special in that it's even got runtime support: `int? x = null; object o = x` assigns a null reference to `o`, not a boxed `Nullable<T>`, and unboxing works similarly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for `null` and assigning `null` to a variable of type `Nullable<T>` is explicitly covered by the compiler.

So

```
int? i = ...
if (i == null) ...
```

is converted to

```
if (!i.HasValue)
```

and

```
i = null;
```

is converted to

```
i = default(Nullable<int>);
```

And a `default(Nullable<int>)` assigns an "empty" (zero-initialized) `Nullable<int>`. Hence its `HasValue` property is `false`, which is the semantic equivalent of a `int?` being `null`.

Comment: Never really thought about it to hard, but I always kinda thought this `Nullable<DateTime> foo = null; foo.Value.Date;` would throw a `NullReferenceException` but TIL it only throws `InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`

Comment: For the curious, you can see the `HasValue` transformation [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACgL8BmAAiNoGEKBvC2jjm+lWgWQAUASnadabcmKkA5AQDsArgBslQgNyjOAX021d3fL1kBLOQBcA/LQQjJnCVLHGAZrQEJaAQgC8tRSttHe10gznxiAE53dU4QsR07DgStIA=). You need to switch to IL view to see it effectively assigning `default(Nullable<int>)`: it's the `ldloca.s` / `initobj` which zero-initialises the variable (which is the same as assigning `default`)

Comment: Also [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACgL8BmAAiNoGEKBvC2j+u/FWgOQAUASwB2AFwD8tBAEp2nNuU7L6xAJwCBCWtlrEZtCVOoyA3PI4BfCpaA===) if you want to see it doing more funky stuff